# Use GetBootstrap in Magento 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magento2

Given i want to use https://getbootstrap.com/ javascript inside magento 2.2.2 framework.

I have done following:
1. Downloaded latest version of bootstrap and popper(dependency) and my `requirejs-config.js` is looking as following

```
var config = {
deps: [
    'js/popper.min',
    'js/bootstrap'
],
shim: {
    'js/bootstrap': {
// These script dependencies should be loaded before loading 'jquery/slick'
        deps: ['jquery', 'js/bootstrap']
    }
}
```

};

Bootstrap v4.1.1

Files are successfully deployed, but first think is that bootstrap is not by default applying javascript to it's elements e.g. Example taken from bootstrap page

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Alerts</h2>
<p>The button with class="close" and data-dismiss="alert" is used to close the alert box.</p>
<p>The alert-dismissible class adds some extra padding to the close button.</p>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

I asume it was not initialised properly so when i try any of following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'js/bootstrap'], function($) {console.log('Ahem1')})
require(['js/bootstrap'], function($) {console.log('Ahem2')})
require(['jquery', 'js/bootstrap'], function($) {
    $('.alert.alert-success').alert();
    $('.alert.alert-success').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
        console.log('i am closed');
    })
})
```

No console logs works, when i try to do `require(['jquery', 'js/popper', 'js/bootstrap']` it also does not work but when i do `require(['jquery', 'js/popper']` then i can see console log working.

Anyone tested before this?
Sorry for my bad formatting, it's my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Guess i am that new to magento2, maybe someone will find it useful, so here it is:

`requiresjs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/popper.min',
        'js/bootstrap',
    ],
    shim: {
        'js/bootstrap': {
    // These script dependencies should be loaded before loading 'jquery/slick'
            deps: ['jquery', 'js/popper.min']
        }
    }
};
```

Then updated path in bootstrap.js where it required or defined popper to use `popper.min`.